# Creating Selenium-RC for other programming languages

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I would like to know if its possible to develop a selenium RC for other languages( i.e. other than php, python, perl, ruby, java and c#). For example, we develop a selenium RC for c++(or any other language that selenium does not support) ,  then it means that we can write the programs in c++ and then perform the testing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  In fact, the original Selenium RC client-side code for the supported languages was machine-generated from the API document.  All you'd have to do is write the appropriate XSLT file to generate them for your chosen language.  That would get you a long way to having a full client, probably close enough to stop there.